# how to login with facebook using facebook csharp sdk in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to implement Facebook login system in my webpage, but didn't succeed below I put my code that I have written:

```
 private Uri RedirectUri
    {
        get
        {
            var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
            uriBuilder.Query = null;
            uriBuilder.Fragment = null;
            uriBuilder.Path = Url.Action("FacebookCallback");
            return uriBuilder.Uri;
        }
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Facebook()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = "appid",
            client_secret = "appsecret",                
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            response_type = "code",
            scope = "email"
        });

        return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = "appid",
            client_secret = "appsecret",
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            code = code
        });

        var accessToken = result.access_token;


        Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

        // update the facebook client with the access token so
        // we can make requests on behalf of the user
        fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

                  dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=first_name,middle_name,last_name,id,email");
        string email = me.email;
        string firstname = me.first_name;
        string middlename = me.middle_name;
        string lastname = me.last_name;


        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

but I have got following error

```
(OAuthException - #1) Error validating client secret.
```

but I am using **client_id = my appid** and **client_secret = my appsecret key**.
Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: take a look to Owin Oauth2 simpler implementations